# Table rows seem to be disapearing

Tags: java, mysql, sql, heidisql

I have a ton of raw html files that I'm parsing and inserting to a MySQL database via a connection in Java.

I'm using "REPLACE INTO" statements and this method:

```
public void migrate(SomeThread thread) throws Exception{
    PreparedStatement threadStatement = SQL.prepareStatement(threadQuery);
    thread.prepareThreadStatement(threadStatement);
    threadStatement.executeUpdate();
    threadStatement.close();

    for(SomeThread.Post P : thread.threadPosts){
        PreparedStatement postStatement = SQL.prepareStatement(postQuery);
        P.preparePostStatement(postStatement);
        postStatement.executeUpdate();
        postStatement.close();
    }
}
```

I am running 3 separate instances of my program each in its own command prompt, with their own separate directory of htmls to parse and commit.

I'm using HeidiSQL to monitor the database and a funny thing is happening where I'll see that I have 500,000 rows in a table at one point for example, then I'll close HeidiSQL and check back later to find that I now have 440,000 rows. The same thing occurs for the two tables that I'm using.

Both of my tables use a primary key called "id", each of their ID's have their own domain but it's possible their values overlap and are overwriting each other? I'm not sure if this could be an issue because I'd think SQL would differentiate between the table's "local" id values.

Otherwise I was thinking it could be that since I'm running 3 separate instances that each have their connection to the DB, some kind of magic is happening where right as one row is being committed, the execution swaps to another commit statement, displaces the table, then back to the first commit and then some more magic that causes the database to roll back the number of rows collected.

I'm pretty new to SQL so I'm not too sure where to start, if somebody has an idea about what the heck is going on and could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `INSERT INTO` instead of `REPLACE INTO`.
Data doesn't disappear.

Here are some tips:

- Do you have another thread running that actually deletes entries?
- Do other people have access to the database?

Not sure what HeidiSQL may do. To exclude that possibility maybe use MySQL Workbench instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah now that I run a COUNT(*) query against my tables I see that all my rows are in fact there.

Most likely the heidiSQL summary page is just a very rough estimate.

Thanks for the suggestion to use workbench pete, I will try it and see if it is better than Heidi as Heidi is freezing up on me on a regular basis.